# Bootstrap Multi-Step Form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm just new to Bootstrap and just learning it. I came to encounter this Multi-Step form on a modal. I am able to edit the elements on it but what I want is to remove the Multi-Step Form from the modal, its quite hard for me since it has jQuery, and I would like to have a separate time to study jQuery. Thanks in advance.

This is the HTML code

````
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <!-- <div id="header_wrap" class="outer">
        <header class="inner">
            <h1 id="project_title"><a href="#">Multi-step Modal Wizard Example</a></h1>
        </header>
    </div> -->

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="main_content_wrap" class="outer">
        <section id="main_content" class="inner">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal">Open modal</button>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div id="submitModal" class="multi-step">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/MultiStep.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.modal').MultiStep({
            title:'Let your potential be seen',
            data:[{
                content:'<center>Welcome and please fill up the following questions for better job results</center>',
                label:'Welcome!!!'
            },{
                content:`<center><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">I have a work experience</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">I am a student/ Fresh graduate</button></center>

                    <br/>Currently Residing In<span><font color = "red">*</font></span><br />

                    <select name="nationality" class="form-control"><option value="nationality">Philippine</option> 
                    <option value="volvo">Afghan</option>          <option value="volvo">Albanian</option>
 </select>

                    <br/>Nationality<span><font color = "red">*</font></span><br />

                    <option value="audi">Bahraini</option>         <option value="volvo">Bangladeshi</option>
                    </select>

                    <br/>Expected Monthly Salary<span><font color = "red">*</font></span><br />

                    <select name="MSE" class="form-control"><option value="MSE">PHP</option> 
                    <option value="volvo">AED</option>          <option value="volvo">AFN</option>
                    <option value="audi">BHD</option>         <option value="volvo">BIF</option>
                    </select>

                    `
                // <input type="nationality" class="form-control" placeholder="Philippines">
            },{
                content:`You can have skip options`,
                skip:true
            },{
                content:`<small>You can include html content as well!</small><br><br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                  </div>
                `,
                skip:true
            },{
                content:`This is the end<br>Hold your breath and count to ten`,
            }],
            final:'You can have your own final message',
            modalSize:'lg'
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove steps, you can just remove elements from the data attribute.

For example, remove

```js
{
    content:`You can have skip options`,
    skip:true
}
```

To delete that step entirely. Same goes for adding additional steps. You can just create new entries for the data attribute (which is an Array).

Comment: I want to remove the form from the modal, so that I don't have to click any button to show the form.

Comment: I am afraid that plugin you are using just handles this the way it does now, using a modal. If you don't want this, I'm afraid you are out of options and either need to change the plugin itself or make something custom.
You can also look for other plugins which might help you achieve what you want. I think this is a good one: http://www.jquery-steps.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use .dialog method and add all the HTML at once what you added for MultiStep's data array (object's content value).